# Можно ли применить сразу две анимации?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Конечно можно просто 2 анимации объединить в одну и получить

```js
$('div').animate({
    backgroundColor:'black',
    height: 0
});
```

Но есть ли способ заставить 2 анимации  воспроизводится одновременно? как это сделать?

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

$('div').animate({
    backgroundColor:'black',
});

$('div').animate({
    height:0
});
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div{
    width: 60px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <div></div>
```

Comment: Я думаю — можно :).

Comment: На данный момент сперва происходит изменение фона и только потом уменьшается высота.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**: Написать всё в один объект:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').animate({
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    height: 0
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

**Вариант 2**: Воспроизводить вне очереди:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').animate({
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    queue: false // Переменная, которая обозначает, что анимация должная запускаться без очереди
  });
  
  $('div').animate({
    height: 0
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    queue: false
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Просто например: кто-то сделал анимацию, и я хочу применить её к своей уже существующий, чтобы они воспроизводились вместе одновременно. Можно конечно вставить код той анимации в свою, но можно ли без этого? а просто воспроизвести их вместе?

Comment: @PeGaS, добавил второй вариант

Comment: Всё, идеально спасибо!

Comment: @PeGaS, не за что :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jz11xock/2/ А вот почему цвет не держится?

Comment: @PeGaS, вторая анимация сбивает первую в начало: https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/jz11xock/4/